# When is a variable reference in a C++11 lambda expression resolved?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I have a (hopefully) simple question about lambda expressions:

```c
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
//----------------------------------------------------------------
void DoSomething()
//----------------------------------------------------------------
{
  std::vector<int> elements;
  elements.push_back(1);
  elements.push_back(2);

  int ref = 1;
  auto printhit = [=](int iSomeNumber)
  {
    if (ref == iSomeNumber)
    {
      printf("Hit: %d\n", iSomeNumber);
    }
    else
    {
      printf("No Hit: %d\n", iSomeNumber);
    }
  };

  ref = 2;
  std::for_each(elements.begin(), elements.end(), printhit);   
}
```

Now, my question is: When I define printhit with capture [=], it prints "Hit: 1". If I pass it by reference [&], it prints "Hit: 2". 
I somehow expected, that the substitution is done within for_each, so that "Hit: 2" is printed no matter how I grant access to "ref".

Can anyone explain this to me?

Thanks,
  Markus

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The capture happens at the location where you declare the lambda.  Just like if you were to create a class object at that point and pass `ref` to its constructor.

Your example is equivalent to this:

```
class Functor
{
public:
    Functor(int r) :ref(r) {}

    void operator()(int iSomeNumber) const
    {
        if (ref == iSomeNumber)
        {
            printf("Hit: %d\n", iSomeNumber);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("No Hit: %d\n", iSomeNumber);
        }    
    }
private:
    int ref;
};

void DoSomething()
//----------------------------------------------------------------
{
  std::vector<int> elements;
  elements.push_back(1);
  elements.push_back(2);

  int ref = 1;
  Functor printhit(ref);

  ref = 2;
  std::for_each(elements.begin(), elements.end(), printhit);   
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I understand what happens to the variables when declaring the lambda with [=] or [&]. My assumption was, that the Functor equivalent code is `std::for_each(elements.begin(), elements.end(), Functor(ref));` which would be bad for performance but leads to a very different behavior.

Comment: Very different, and very peculiar.  I honestly can't imagine why one would expect/assume that.

Comment: @badstoms "My assumption was, that the Functor equivalent code is std::for_each(elements.begin(), elements.end(), Functor(ref));" - that is functionally identical to having an extra argument in the `operator()` parameter list... wouldn't need an extra `[=]` notation to opperate like that.

Comment: Perfectly right, and I need to make my previous statement more precise. I didn't assume this behavior, it was just one possibility for me. I originally showed the example to a colleague of mine and he asked, what happens if you change "ref" after the definition of the lambda. With the functor equivalent, this is easy to understand now. Thank all of you again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I guess, that the following parts of the C++ standard apply:

> **5.1.2.14:** 
> An entity is captured by copy if it is implicitly captured and the capture-default is = or if it is explicitly
> captured with a capture that does not include an &. **For each entity captured by copy, an unnamed nonstatic
> data member is declared in the closure type.** The declaration order of these members is unspecified.
> The type of such a data member is the type of the corresponding captured entity if the entity is not a
> reference to an object, or the referenced type otherwise. [ Note: If the captured entity is a reference to a
> function, the corresponding data member is also a reference to a function. —end note ]

> **5.1.2.21:** 
> **When the lambda-expression is evaluated, the entities that are captured by copy are used to direct-initialize
> each corresponding non-static data member of the resulting closure object.** (For array members, the array
> elements are direct-initialized in increasing subscript order.) These initializations are performed in the
> (unspecified) order in which the non-static data members are declared. [ Note: This ensures that the
> destructions will occur in the reverse order of the constructions. —end note ]

Answer (score 1):

What would be the point of having them both operate the same way?  The point of `[=]` is to support capture by copy *instead* of by reference.

Imagine if `[=]` wasn't available: if you know a runtime value at the point in the code where the lambda's defined and want the lambda to use it ever after, how could that value be made available to the lambda code?  While `DoSomething()` is running by-ref `[&]` access to its local `ref` variable might serve, but what if you want to have the lambda's lifetime outlive the local scope in `DoSomething()` that contains it, or want to change the value of `ref` without that affecting future calls to the lambda?  Conceptually, you could have the language forbid all these things (use after `ref` is changed or changes to `ref` or calls of the lambda after `ref` is changed or out of scope), or the programmer could go to elaborate lengths to put the value of `ref` somewhere for the lambda to use (e.g. on the heap, with the need to manage deallocation, or in some static buffer with re-entrance and thread-safety issues), but to make it convenient the language provides `[=]`.  The compiler-generated lambda effectively takes responsibility for storing and destructing/deallocating the copy of `ref`.